# GSON NoSuchFieldError Exception within Android

Tags: android, exception, gson

I have an Android app that is crashing with the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy.IDENTITY
at ir.<init>(App:72)
ja.a(App:653)
at ja.doInBackground(App:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
... 4 more
App crashed! Process: com.company.app
```

This doesn't crash on my Nexus S running Android 4.0 ICS, however it is crashing on another beta test device that I don't have access to.  I am using the Google GSON 2.1 library.

I am also using ProGuard however if that was causing the issue I would think that would also cause the issue on my Nexus S.

Any idea why this would not occur on my test device and how I can resolve the issue?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NoSuchFieldError.html -> "Note that this can only occur when inconsistent class files are being loaded. " possibly an android version problem?

Comment: How would the class files be inconsistent?  The field that it is referring to is a library that I am distributing with the app, com.google.gson v2.1

Comment: I dont know, its just what's written in the Android Reference...

Comment: Got it many of this error. It is only for HTC devices with 2.3.5 ROM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was caused by a custom Android ROM, I assume that inconsistent class files within the ROM were causing the issue as suggested in the question comments.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by skipping GSON from obfuscation.

-keep class com.google.gson.Gson {*;}

Comment: Welcome on SO. Maybe you could add more explanation to this solution. Please have a look to the FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq to see how to make good post :) Regards